# Display custom error message in wcf invalid method in route table

Tags: wcf, rest, exception

I have implemented a RESTful API using wcf and I use System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(...) to map the methods to URLs. If a user types an invalid url (i.e. a url that does not map to a method), say myapiurl/geeet/ instead of myapiurl/get/ then currently a standard error message like "Method not allowed" is displayed.

How do I customize this error message?

I have tried Application_Error in Global.asax, but it does not catch the exception.
I have also implemented a IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior, but it also does not catch this error.
Neither does the WebHttpBehavior I have implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Method not allowed" (HTTP status code 405) message means the server is receiving a request from a client using an HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) that is not allowed by the server (IIS). For example the client is submitting a PUT request and IIS is not configured to accept PUT. I think by default, IIS only supports GET and POST.

A bad URI, as you describe in your question, generally results in a HTTP status code of 404 resource not found. Sound like your IIS configuration may be causing your issue since you can't trap the exception at either the ASP.NET or WCF layer.